# Remove a person from arrayList of person

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist, google-plus

I have Google plus included in my app. I am trying to share my app to specific person from the list of friends that are shown in a ListView.

On selecting the person in the listview I add them to a recipient arraylist.

like below:

```
 private ArrayList<Person> recipients;
 recipients= new ArrayList<Person>();
 recipients.add(PlusShare.createPerson(person_ID, person_DISPLAY_NAME));
```

I also have a button that opens share activity and uses the recipients arraylist to get the person id, name to share. This part works fine.

Now I would like to remove a particular person from the recipients array list. This is also done on item click.

I tried the following:

```
 recipients.remove(person_ID);
```

This way I am not able to remove the item from arraylist. How to remove persons details from recipeints arraylist?

Comment: are `person_ID` unique?? or some with duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove an object of class `Person` obviously.

Try this:

```
recipients.remove(PlusShare.createPerson(person_ID, person_DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Or you can iterate over all persons in your list, compare the IDs and remove the element with matching ID.

```
for (Iterator<Person> it = recipients.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Person p = it.next();
    if (p.getId() == person_ID) { // <-- supposed that getId() exists
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code around this line: `com.ylg.me.Friends$2.onItemClick(Friends.java:224)`? It's just an NPE

Comment: @ Ridcully - Iterator worked fine. I didn't worry much about the code without the iterator. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Note, that Iterator is used to be able to remove element from list while iterating over its elements. If you try this with a for() loop you'd get an exception. Also, since person_ID is unique you can add a `break` after the `it.remove()` statement.

Comment: Didn't get the for loop part? can you please explain when will i get the exception?

Comment: If you would do something like this: `for (Person p : recipients) { if (p.getId() == person_ID) { recipients.remove(p); }}` you'd get an Exception. Hence the use of the Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `person_ID` are unique you can use Map interface instead, you can use the `person_ID` as the **key** and **value** is the object of the `Person`

**sample:**

```
Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
```

to put the object to the map

```
map.put(person_ID, PlusShare.createPerson(person_ID, person_DISPLAY_NAME));
```

to get/remove the map

```
if(map.get(person_ID) != null)
   map.remove(person_ID);
```

On thing why to use Map is that it has the speed of `O(1)` big-O

Answer (score 0):

I would use an additional Map to store the Person objects referenced by their IDs. This way, you could be able to get the correct object to remove to the list.

```
private ArrayList<Person> recipients;
recipients= new ArrayList<Person>();
private Map<String,Person> recipientsById = new HashMap<String,Person>;
Person newPerson = PlusShare.createPerson(person_ID, person_DISPLAY_NAME);
recipients.add(newPerson);
recipientsById.put(personId,newPerson);
```

That way, removing an object from the list would simply become :

```
recipients.remove(recipientsById.get(person_ID));
recipientsById.remove(person_ID);
```

Of course, there are now 2 variables to handle, and this may look over complicated for this. So there are 2 more solutions to use only one variable :

- You can browse in your arraylist to look for the person having the personID, and remove this one
- You can replace your arraylist by the HashMap, which could work depending what usage you hve of it.

So there are 3 solutions for your. Choosing the correct one depends on you and implementation details that are not stated in your question.

(Edit : Both last solutions are the ones given by @rod and @Ridcully)